# Re-importing old teams application into teams dev portal

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, azure-bot-service

This isn't a code issue more than a configuration issue.

I was working previously on a teams bot application, we used to work on Microsoft Teams Desktop App.

After successfully publishing the application, we stopped working on the app for about a year, in that year working on Teams Desktop App became deprecated and instead we had to work on: [Teams Dev Portal](https://dev.teams.microsoft.com)

The issue is the following:

When trying to re-import the old app package on Dev Portal, I'm having the following issue:

> An app with that ID already exists in your organization's app store. Please change the app ID and try again.

And I can't create and submit a new app since the validation by Microsoft will fail due to the following condition:

> You can't update the Id of the App you want to publish

So the question is the following:

- Is there a way to re-import the old app package from teams admin center or somewhere else into teams dev portal??

Answer (score 0):

I presume you're using this dev portal: https://dev.teams.microsoft.com/apps

It sounds like the app still exists in the org, and you can check by using the Teams Admin portal instead: https://admin.teams.microsoft.com/

You can delete or even update your app using that portal

Comment: Yes indeed the app do exist in the portal, can't I re-import this app into dev portal somehow?

Comment: Try delete it from the Admin portal first

Comment: I can't, since the published one is being used by clients and have users. I need to find a way to re-import it using the same App Id

Comment: ah ok, so you want to keep it, but just update it somehow? If so, you just need to increase the version number. That might work in the dev portal (I'm not 100% sure, given you situation, so test it out), but for sure in the Admin portal there's an option to upgrade an existing app.

Comment: Yes I can update a new version with just changing the App Id manually, but I prefer not doing that.
I mean I can do whatever I wanna do on dev portal, export the package, and change the App Id manually in the manifest and upload a new version.
But what I wanna do is import the same app that exists on the admin center to dev portal. Thus, having the same app with the same app Id on dev portal

Comment: I don't mean the **App Id**, I mean the **Version Number**. For example:

```{
 "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/json-schemas/teams/v1.12/MicrosoftTeams.schema.json",
 "manifestVersion": "1.12",
 "version": "2.0.2",
 "id": "c32d8b45-92fe-44f6-8b61-42c2107dfe87",
```

Comment: don't change `c32d8b45-92fe-44f6-8b61-42c2107dfe87`, change `"version": "2.0.2"` to something else, like `"version": "2.0.3"`

Comment: Here's a sample schema, you can see it more clearly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/resources/schema/manifest-schema#sample-manifest